# how to make html contact form from contact 7 in Wordpress 5.8.1?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design, contact-form-7

I am a web designer as well as a WordPress beginner! I am unable to invent the way of the previously designed Contact form to interpret into Raw HTML section as CSS is not coming in Page Builders these days, also I am unable to create an HTML template Form (as it is), to another form of Contact Form 7.

Code of the Form:

```
<h1>Elegant Contact Form</h1>
<form class="cf">
  <div class="half left cf">
    <input type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="email" id="input-email" placeholder="Email address">
    <input type="text" id="input-subject" placeholder="Subject">
  </div>
  <div class="half right cf">
    <textarea name="message" type="text" id="input-message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  </div>  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="input-submit">
</form>
```

And CSS is as follows:

```
@import "compass/css3";

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather);
$red: #e74c3c;

*, 
*:before, 
*:after {
   @include box-sizing(border-box); 
}

html, body {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
  padding: 1em;
}

h1 {
   text-align: center;
   color: #a8a8a8;
   @include text-shadow(1px 1px 0 rgba(white, 1));
}

form {
   max-width: 600px;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 20px auto;
  
  input, textarea {
     border:0; outline:0;
     padding: 1em;
     @include border-radius(8px);
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     margin-top: 1em;
     font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
     @include box-shadow(0 1px 1px rgba(black, 0.1));
     resize: none;
    
    &:focus {
       @include box-shadow(0 0px 2px rgba($red, 1)!important);
    }
  }
  
  #input-submit {
     color: white; 
     background: $red;
     cursor: pointer;
    
    &:hover {
       @include box-shadow(0 1px 1px 1px rgba(#aaa, 0.6)); 
    }
  }
  
  textarea {
      height: 126px;
  }
}


.half {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.right { width: 50%; }

.left {
     margin-right: 2%; 
}


@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .half {
     width: 100%; 
     float: none;
     margin-bottom: 0; 
  }
}


/* Clearfix */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Output:

[image: Final Form Output]

Comment: just replace the input tags with cf7 form tags.

Comment: you cannot use `<form>` elements in your html in CF7, these will be added for you by the plugin.  If you need to design multi-column form layouts as well as add custom CSS for a specific form, then you may want to try out the [Smart Grid-layout extension for CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/), it comes will [multiple tutorials](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLblJwjs_dFBsynXEstrV3fCIC7GBmK9HW) on how to build complex form layouts.